# Why doesn't scikit-learn's Bunch class implement the __dir__() method?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, ipython

The following code loads a scikit-learn Bunch object:

```
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
```

Then, on IPython, tab completion to get the list of attributes of `iris` does not work for the most desired attributes like `data`, `target`.  A quick digging around found that [those attributes are exposed via the underlying dictionary](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0c879ba55193f13420934fa01bbcae88cad53c14/sklearn/datasets/base.py#L29).

I would imagine that, if the Bunch class implemented the `__dir__()` method, it would report those attributes.  Any particular reason the `__dir__()` method is not implemented?

Comment: `Bunch` is a subclass of `dict`, so it inherits form that (or object).